# Include details from multiple classes in one dox file

Tags: java, doxygen

I have a set of classes which perform some date calculation. Inside each class, I have documented some general information about the class and sample usage of it, for example:

```
/**
 * \brief Get the number of release date for a given year
 * 
 * \b Example:
 * 
 * \code
 *   GetReleaseDateCount col = new GetReleaseDateCount(1990);
 *   col.calculate();
 * \endcode
 */
public class GetReleaseDateCount
```

So is it possible to copy all those details from different classes and make them part of content in a single dox file? I have tried to put the following inside a dox file:

```
\copydetails GetReleaseDateCount
```

but it does not seems to work.

Anyone has any idea?

Thanks
CS

------------------------------ UPDATE --------------------------------------

I have also tried another approach, in the class1.java, I added:

```
/** @addtogroup group1
 *  @{
 */

/**
 * @details
 *
 * Class1 Details
 */

/** @} */
public class Class1
```

and then in the main.dox, I have:

```
/*!
   \page page1 Page1

   \tableofcontents  

   \section Classes Information

   \copydoc group1

 */
```

Doing that, nothing will be shown on main.dox. The content only shown on Class1's detail.

But if I change the Class1.java to:

```
/** @addtogroup group1
 * 
 * @details
 *
 * Class1 Details
 */
```

then the main.dox will contains those Class1 details, but the detail for Class1 will be blank (the html page for Class1).

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried \copydoc?

> Copies a documentation block from the object specified by
>    and pastes it at the location of the command. This
>   command can be useful to avoid cases where a documentation block would
>   otherwise have to be duplicated or it can be used to extend the
>   documentation of an inherited member.

Comment: You will need to provide more information. What is it you are getting? What is that you actually expect? Also post your doxygen file. Do you have a mainpage? I am able to get the kind of documentation that I think you are looking for.

Comment: Oh, the idea is, I will put documentation in each .java file, and I will have one main dox file which group and list all those documentation. For example, in class1.java, I will have "/** Doc for Class1 ..." and in class2.java, I will have "/** Doc for Class2 ...". Then in main.dox, I want to reference those doc in Class1 and Class2 so that in the generated page, it will have "Doc for Class1 .... Doc for Class2 ...".

Comment: I have updated the original question to include the main.dox and class1.java. Thanks

Comment: When you do `@copydoc group1`, it will copy the documentation under `@addtogroup group1` block and NOT the entire documentation under group1. If you do `@copydoc Class1` it will copy documentation for Class1 but without any reference to Class1. Try `@ref Class1 @copydoc Class1` etc. in the mainpage.